# Table structure for relating a message to a set of specific users or to all users

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

## Few words about my idea

Working on some web based, education project. Creating question-answer system for this project. There is some logical difficulties that I can't figure out:

There are teachers and students between users. Every student selects some course during signup.

I have 5 tables: `users`, `courses`, `lessons`, `questions`, `answers`.

There might be 2 types of questions:

1. `User` based. For ex, when teacher wants to send questions to specific users and vise-versa (users may post question to teachers too).
2. `Course-lesson` combination based. For ex, teacher wants to post questions to all course listeners based on lesson, they are currently in.

## What I've done

I've created `questions from-to` (qft) table

```
CREATE TABLE `questions from-to` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `qid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `from_uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to_uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `qft.from_uid_users.id` (`from_uid`),
  KEY `qft.to_uid_users.id` (`to_uid`),
  KEY `qft.qid_qe.id` (`qid`),
  CONSTRAINT `qft.from_uid_users.id` FOREIGN KEY (`from_uid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `qft.qid_qe.id` FOREIGN KEY (`qid`) REFERENCES `questions_and_exercises` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `qft.to_uid_users.id` FOREIGN KEY (`to_uid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Which looks like that

[image]

- `qid` - is question id, connects this table with `questions`, based
  on `id`
- `from_uid` - from user id (question sender id), connects this table with `users`, based
  on `id`
- `to_uid` - to user id (question receiver id), connects this table with `users`, based
  on `id`

So I tried to create some universal solution for both:

- students and teacher so they can post questions to each others. **ok**
- teacher can post to some users specific questions. **ok**

BUT there is a problem

## The problem is

What if, teacher wants to post question for all course listeners? I already have `user-course` relationship table, but, currently I need to add one-by-one user id's into `questions from-to` table so they can receive questions. I have no idea, how can I design this table for both situations: for "mass questioning" based on `course-lesson` combination and for "user-user" type question posting (teacher sends questions to specific students and vise-versa)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to have a special code in `to_uid` that your application knows to interpret as "show to all users." When it encounters a `to_uid` of -1 (or whatever you chose) then it does a select for all students listening to that course, and displays the question just as if their IDs had all been separately listed in `to_uid`. Depending on how your application is organized, you should only have to implement this special check in a small number of places.

Answer (score 0):

A bit similar to problem discribed here. Take a look at the solution suggested.

[Messaging System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571485/how-to-implement-a-messaging-system-between-users/15571700)