# How to implement a messaging system between users?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, architecture

I need to implement a messaging system at a web site. There are users and these users be able to send messages to eachother. How can I achieve this? What sort of database structure I need?

What I have right now is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SenderId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ReceiverId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MessageContent` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `MessageDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Viewed` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `FK_Message_User_idx` (`SenderId`),
  KEY `FK_Message_Receiver_idx` (`ReceiverId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Message_Sender` FOREIGN KEY (`SenderId`) REFERENCES `user` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Message_Receiver` FOREIGN KEY (`ReceiverId`) REFERENCES `user` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3
```

This is MySql create table script. Basicly, I store senderid, receiverid and message. Problem is, if receiver will delete his message, message will be gone from sender too. I want to implement a structure like an email box. What do you suggest?

P.S. I am developing project with ASP.NET MVC 3 and C#.

Comment: Perhaps you need to create two copies of the message, one for the sender and one for the receiver.  What have you tried?

Comment: @DanPuzey, no, I haven't tried your suggestion, but I thought about it. Right now I am thinking of a good solution for this.

Comment: If it's always 1 sender and 1 receiver then you can just have 2 flags of whether the message was deleted from either mailbox. That way you can avoid having duplicate messages in your system. If you have multiple receivers though that won't work and you're going to have to duplicate the message.

Comment: @VARAK there is no need for multiple receivers. its 1-to-1. can you please write a small answer for your suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to an inbox for each sender (and maybe a "sent messages" mailbox too), in a normalized database you could model that as a `Mailbox` table.

```
Mailbox
______
MailboxId
UserId -- who the mailbox belongs to
MailboxTypeId -- is it an inbox, sent, drafts box...
```

Your Message table would then have a many-to-many relationship with one user's sent Mailbox and one user's inbox. This relationship is modeled as a `MessageMailbox` table.

```
Message
_______
MessageId
MessageText
-- .. other fields, e.g. MessageDate


MessageMailbox
______________
MailboxId
MessageId
```

When you delete a message from a mailbox, you can then remove the row in `MessageMailbox` that says that the message is in the mailbox you want to delete it from.

To create a message you save the message in the `Message` table, so you have MessageId=2 and MessageText="Hi".
When the message is sent (say for instance I'm sending it to you), you create two rows in MessageMaibox, one with the messageId of the created message and MailboxId=23 (assuming that 23 corresponds to my "sent" maibox in the Mailbox table), the other with same messageID and MaiboxId=42 (assuming 42 is your inbox in the Mailbox table).

This lets you send a message to multiple recipients (just add a row in MessageMaibox for every inbox the message should arrive), or even, theoretically, to have a message with multiple senders, which is something that email don't usually provide but the application you're developing may want to allow.

Comment: quite interesting. Can you please describe a little bit further? In this approach how will I send a message?

Comment: @piedpiper expanded explanation on how to send

Comment: I would expand on this idea. You can put more data in the MessageMailbox table such as whether or not the message has been read, deleted, timestamps, if it was replied to, etc..

Comment: @Shlomo absolutely! With the same mechanism you mention, you could add tags too, or "urgent" flags... But also this DB structure makes it relatively easy to allow users to add their own personalized folders (e.g. "archive"): you just add a new MailboxType and associate a new Mailbox with teh new MailboxType to a user. Archiving a message then just changes the corresponding row in MessageMailbox.

Comment: Nice approach. One issue though.. when you want to see a message in your inbox, how do you know who sent it to you? I suggest that MessageMailbox has a reference column to hold either the sender (if it  is an "inbox" message) or a recipient (if it is a "sent" message)

Comment: @Samson you're right, good catch! But maybe the MessageMailbox is not the right place to store the "role" (who's the sender, who are the recipients). That sounds more related to the message itself. Deleting a message from your "sent" folder deletes a row in MessageMailbox, but it should not delete from the message the information that you were the sender. Probably it would be enough to have a "To", "From" and "CC" fields on the message table where you could have ;-separated lists of accounts as for email, how does it sound to you?

Comment: No, I m currently implementing this and I stand to my point because it s more accurate. Having To and From in message table doesn t help. If I broadcast the same message to 10 users I can only fill the "To". It s the link-table that actually describes a message being sent to someone (or from someone) so it s the right place to store the "other end"

Comment: @Samson I meant that you could have "To" contain a list of recipients separated by ";" like in emails, but that is not the only way to do it. The point I was trying to make is that MessageMailbox says in what mailboxes a message is currently stored, while TO stores the information of whom the message was originally sent to. If you send me a message, but I delete it, your message will no longer be in my inbox but will remain in your "sent" folder and you should still see that you had sent it to me. However if you are implementing this chances are you are right. Usually practice > theory :)

Comment: Well it looks nice in my code like this :) If I encounter any issues I can adapt on the go. Thanks for the structure though!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a field

```
deleted int default 0
```

and add to your queries

```
and deleted = 0
```

Additionally, if you need, you may make statuses to that field.

For example,

```
deleted = 1   -  deleted by sender
deleted = 2   -  delted by reciever
deleted = 3   -   deleted by both
```

If you have several reveivers, your tables should be different:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `SenderId` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `MessageContent` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
   `MessageDate` datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE recieversmessages (
    receiverId int,
    messageId int,
     viewed int,
    primary key(receiverId, messageId)
)
```

Comment: I don't need a recovery mechanism for private messages. But you answer is easy to implement. I will keep this in mind. But one question. In first case which there are no multiple receivers, do I have to add single message to messages table or 2?

Comment: You have to add single message. That's strange to make 2 copies of message. What for?